# Notepadqq - fold all levels?

Tags: notepadqq

When using notepadqq it lets you fold code up by pressing a little arrow near the start of e.g. a function (I think this may also be called collapsing the code). But I would like to know how to collapse all the levels in my code without having to do this individually. I would think this would be a pretty simply function but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: What version of `notepadqq` are you on?

Comment: @GraysonKent version 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

**Behind the scenes:**

This is defined in `notepadqq`'s [`libs/codemirror/addon/fold/foldcode.js`](https://github.com/notepadqq/CodeMirror/blob/master/addon/fold/foldcode.js) with [this function](https://github.com/notepadqq/CodeMirror/blob/master/addon/fold/foldcode.js#L97):

```
  CodeMirror.commands.foldAll = function(cm) {
    cm.operation(function() {
      for (var i = cm.firstLine(), e = cm.lastLine(); i <= e; i++)
        cm.foldCode(CodeMirror.Pos(i, 0), null, "fold");
    });
```

This was added back in 2014 with [this commit](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/commit/1858667ffa0ada37e5c8a0c4adaee0c13c0ee282).

**Things to try:**

Their [documentation](https://github.com/notepadqq/CodeMirror/blob/68b2994f012fbb15450b8dfd6bc3c061a42b3491/demo/folding.html#L31) hints that you could select all text(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>) and format as a block(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>):

Also, if you are running an incredibly old version of `notepadqq`, you could try updating the code mirror following the steps from [their documentation](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/wiki/How-to-update-CodeMirror) and adjust for your version.

**Edit:** 
Since you are running 1.01 which is the latest version, you may have to put in a feature request [here](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/issues/new).